# what is classSet?

Tags: reactjs

please explain it...

```
<div className={classSet({
       'Cell': true,
       'Cell--highlighted': highlighted,
       'Cell--hovered': hovered
})}></div>
```

Comment: note:i see that when i using react drag and drop library

Comment: Found by searching Google for "react classSet" https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/class-name-manipulation.html

Comment: I dont know why this question is closed. I have the exact same question.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The key in object classSet is a name of css class. The value is a logical expression - if is true - class will be added to DOM element, if false, will not.

This library is now deprecated, look at this:
https://github.com/JedWatson/classnames